# Under what assumptions it's true that $g(A-B)=g(A)-g(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R^n}$. Under what assumptions it's true that $g(A-B)=g(A)-g(B)$, for every subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the domain of $g$? (I mean which functions $g$ satisfies this property?). I would require $g$ to be of class $C^1$, but I'm not sure if this is enaugh for the truth of that statement.
If there are no such functions (except linear functions), do we need additional assumption on $A,B$? If so, which?
What do you suggest?

Comment: I gave an answer, but I think I misunderstood your question, sorry.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ subsets or points in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I forgot, they are subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you want the result hold for all $A$,$B$, or for two specific $A$,$B$?

Comment: I asked for a general result; maybe this holds only for specific $A,B$.

Comment: You wrote "some" $A,B$.. which makes it sound like you're only asking the property to hold for a given pair of subsets.

Comment: Just because I suspect this need not hold for all $A,B$

Comment: It is very unclear what you're really asking here. I thought it was "which functions g (possibly of a certain type) have the property that $g(A \setminus B) = g(A) \setminus g(B)$ for every pair of subsets $A,B$", but now I'm not so sure anymore. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Svinepels Sure I'm fixing

Comment: I would think that all injective functions would satisfy this, and no non-injective functions will. More concretely, I think the specific property that needs to hold is that $g(B\setminus A)\cap g(A\setminus B) = \emptyset$.

Comment: It should be linear

Answer (score 1):

Answer. If and only if $g$ is one-to-one.

It is straightforward to show it. The "$\Rightarrow$" part is obvious, while, for "$\Leftarrow$", if $g(a)= g(b)$ and $a\ne b$, then for $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{a\}$ we get that $$\{g(a)\}=g(A\smallsetminus B)\ne g(A)\smallsetminus g(B)=\varnothing$$